# Problems with Extrusion

Tags: extrude

When a non-circular shape is extruded, the end vertices are not the specified distance from the beginning.

[image]

To the left is a circular mesh extruded with a duplicate circle on top.  It looks good.  To the right is a non-circular object with a duplicate moved to where the top should be.  It's wrong.

I believe this is a bug, but I would love to hear that I can get it working.

Using blender 3.6.1.

[image]

Comment: How are you defining the direction the extrusion is  made in? Maybe share this file on https://blend-exchange.com/ , to help clear this up quickly.

Comment: The extrusion is specified in global coordinates.  (1,1,1).  The one on the right also includes rotation, but it's not the problem.  The file has a sample without rotation.

Comment: Are you sure your Tool-Extrusion (Which sets the orientation to 'Normal') and the move of the duplicate are in the same orientation? Your .blend opens with  a 'Global' Transform orientation. So far, if I keep a close eye on my orientations, I can't reproduce this anomaly. I could, of course, be missing the point.

Comment: "The extrusion is specified in global coordinates." How exactly do you specify them? Because just like Robin I cannot reproduce your error. First of all the tool is set to _Normal_ (showing in the top left of the viewport), but when you manually enter the values in the tool options on the bottom left (which are set to _Global_ by default) it works as expected. But if you do not enter the values actually and instead drag the mouse with the tool: how do you specify global (1, 1, 1)? By the way not important for the issue, but the translation per axis is not the distance the vertices are moved.

Comment: The problem comes from using "normal" coordinates.  When I switch from normal to global, it works properly.  I am not sure why this object has misaligned normals and how to fix it.

Comment: After some trials, I found that the issue was the rotation, not the extrusion.  Blender changes the center of rotation and hence the misalignment.  If anybody is interested, I will provide more info.